# React - axios post request with body

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

New to react and working on a project with a backend.
so far I have been using axios with `Get`, `Delete`, `Get` with **params**.

I have a little trouble with my post request with a body.
I think my syntax is okay, however, my issue is how do I get certain data depending on the user request.

**E.G:**: There is a list of coupons on the website that's coming with a `Get` request from my backend and a button of `Purchase now`.
What I would like to do is when an `authenticated` user presses the button, that specific coupon would be send as a `post` request with its body.

I am really uncertain of how to do it since I am really new to react.

**Purchase Coupon Componenet:**

```
interface CustomerState {
    coupons: any;
}

class PurchaseCoupon extends Component <{}, CustomerState, CouponModel> {
    public constructor(props: {}) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            coupons: store.getState().couponState.coupons,
        };
    }

    public async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post<CouponModel>(globals.urls.purchasedCoupon,
                {
                data: {
                    
                },
                
                });
            store.dispatch(couponPurchasedAction(response.data)); // Updating global state
            this.setState({ coupons: response.data });
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    }


    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <div className="PurchaseCoupon">
                
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default PurchaseCoupon;
```

**CouponList Component:**

```
interface CouponListState {

    coupons: CouponModel[];

}

class CouponList extends Component<{}, CouponListState>{

    public constructor(props: {}) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            coupons: store.getState().couponState.coupons,
        };
    }

    public async componentDidMount() {

            try {
                const response = await axios.get<CouponModel[]>(globals.urls.allCoupons);
                store.dispatch(couponsAction(response.data)); // Updating global state
                this.setState({ coupons: response.data });
            } catch (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        }

    public render(): JSX.Element {

        return (
            <div className="CouponList">
                <div className="top">
                    <h1>Coupon List</h1>
                </div>/
                <div className="card">
                    <Box m={4} pt={4} >
                        <Grid container spacing={6}
                            direction="row"
                            justifyContent="space-evenly"
                            alignItems="center"
                            style={{ minHeight: '80vh' }}
                        >
                            {
                                this.state.coupons.map(c => (
                                    <Grid item xs={6} sm={4} >
                                        <Card2 key={c.id} coupon={c} />
                                    </Grid>
                                ))
                            }
                        </Grid>
                    </Box>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CouponList;
```

this component contains a `Get` request of all coupons on back-end with works properly. the user can see it as a list of cards and on the buttom and button with `Purchase now`.

**Card Component:**

```
interface CardProps {
  coupon?: CouponModel;
}

export default function MediaCard(props: CardProps) {

const history = useHistory();

function handleSubmit(){ 
 if(!store.getState().authState.user) {   
  notify.error(SccMsg.NOT_LOGGED);   
   history.push('/login')  
 }
}
 
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardActionArea>
     
        <CardContent>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>       
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">   
                
            {'PRODUCT: ' + props.coupon.title}
            <br/>
            <br/>
          </Typography>
          <CardMedia
          className={classes.media}
          image={CouponImage}
          title="Coupons"

        />
        <br/>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
          {'WHAT YOU GET: ' + props.coupon.description}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="h3" component="h2">
            {props.coupon.price + "$"}
          </Typography>     
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textPrimary" component="p">
            {'Only ' + props.coupon.amount + ' Left!'}
          </Typography>
          </ThemeProvider>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
      <CardActions>
        {/* <Button size="small" color="primary">
          <span> </span>
        </Button> */}
        <Button onClick={handleSubmit} size="small" color="primary">
          PURCHASE NOW!
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

I have been trying to research on a way to do so. but related questions are either old or did not help my matter.

Hope I am clear on my question.

Thanks.

Comment: @SinanYaman Hi, I was not trying to send a body with a `GET` request. I was trying to send the body with a `POST` request.

Comment: Sorry about that, misread :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a few remarks:

Why are you mixing class based components and functional components? Lifecycle methods have been implemented in function components with hooks (e.g. useEffect)

I see you are using store.getState() in your components, try creating some selectors (with reselect) and hook (pun intended) them up to your components.

```
const userLoggedIn: (state: RootState) => state.authState.user
```

when it comes to purchasing a coupon

dispatch a purchase coupon action which then puts your application in to the pending state, assuming you use redux-toolkit, you can use a createAsyncThunk to generate pending, error, success and idle states.

The result of this side effect can then update your application's state